# google cloud sql - UDF support

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm a little bit confused here. In Google Cloud SQL [FAQ page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#supportmysqlfeatures) stated that UDF doesn't supported. However, I'm able to import existing functions or create a new function in the database. So, just for confirmation, did Google Cloud SQL support UDF creation now ? We need to verify this because we plan to move existing database to Google Cloud SQL which using a lot of UDF. I'm setup MySQL database version 5.6 (preview) in Cloud SQL

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

actually, as documented, UDF are not supported and there is no estimate date for their official support.

You may want to subscribe to google-cloud-sql-announce group to be informed about new feature release.

Regards
Paolo